# How to prevent the user from seeing other subscribers email in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, email-client

I created a django newsletter functionality where users subscribe and I use the emails subscribed to send the newsletter to those emails. Now the problem I want your help is when I send the newsletter to the subscribers the receiver can see other subscribers emails. I have tried to add BCC but still not working. bellow is my `views.py`

```
def send_newsletter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.POST['subject']
        body = request.POST['body']
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        # get all subscribers' email addresses
        subscribers = Newsletter.objects.all()
        to_email = [subscriber.email for subscriber in subscribers]
        bcc = [instance.email if instance.email != from_email else None for instance in subscribers]

        html_message = get_template('newsletter/newsletter.html').render({'message': body})

        # Create the email message object
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            strip_tags(body),
            from_email,
            to_email,
            bcc,
            headers={'To': 'Undisclosed Recipients <{}>'.format(from_email)}
        )
        email.content_subtype = 'html'
        email.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        email.send()

        # Save newsletter to database
        newsletter = NewsletterText.objects.create(subject=subject, body=body, status='Published')
        newsletter.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Newsletter sent successfully')
        return redirect('blog:home')

    return render(request, 'newsletter/send_newsletter.html')
```

I also tried to use Undisclosed recipients as the code bellow shows

```
def send_newsletter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = request.POST['subject']
        body = request.POST['body']
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        # get all subscribers' email addresses
        subscribers = Newsletter.objects.all()
        to_email = [subscriber.email for subscriber in subscribers]
        bcc = []

        html_message = get_template('newsletter/newsletter.html').render({'message': body})

        # Create the email message object
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            strip_tags(body),
            from_email,
            to_email,
            bcc,
            headers={'To': 'Undisclosed Recipients <{}>'.format(from_email)}
        )
        email.content_subtype = 'html'
        email.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        email.send()

        # Save newsletter to database
        newsletter = NewsletterText.objects.create(subject=subject, body=body, status='Published')
        newsletter.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Newsletter sent successfully')
        return redirect('blog:home')

    return render(request, 'newsletter/send_newsletter.html')
```

still the subscriber will get the email and be able to see other subscribers email.
I expected the receiver will not be able to see other subscribers emails. What am I doing wrong here.
How can i prevent one subscriber from seeing others emails. I have even tried not to pass `to_email` in `EmailMessage()` Thank you

Comment: Set `to_email` empty.

Comment: what do you mean like `to_email = []` like the empty list?

Answer (score 0):

Don't send email to `to` recipients but only to `bcc`:

```
        to_email = [subscriber.email for subscriber in subscribers]
        bcc = [instance.email if instance.email != from_email else None for instance in subscribers]

        # Create the email message object
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            strip_tags(body),
            from_email,
            None, # HERE
            bcc + to_email,  # HERE
            headers={'To': 'Undisclosed Recipients <{}>'.format(from_email)}
        )
```

Comment: After following you code and implementing it am still able to see other subscribers. I don't know why it didn't work because the logic is good it should have worked